# Topological Circuit Simulator

Tags: circuit-construction, topological-quantum-computing, quirk

Does something like [Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk) exist for topological (eg. *braided*) circuits?

Alternatively, any ideas on how @[CraigGidney](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/119/craig-gidney) is getting [these circuits](http://algassert.com/post/1804) (or something similar)?

[image]

Comment: @CraigGidney any thoughts?

Comment: Those figures were created manually with [sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/products/sketchup-free), which is a 3d modelling tool. There was no simulation involved, only careful application of known rules. I have been working on [a tool to both edit and simulate the braids](https://github.com/Strilanc/SurfaceSketcher), but it is very incomplete at the moment. And it may switch paradigms completely (to lattice surgery) before advancing more.

Comment: @CraigGidney You are awesome!! Thank you for all your contributions to open source quantum software!

Comment: @CraigGidney Would you consider posting an answer so that I may accept it? Alternatively, I can self-answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those figures were created manually with [sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/products/sketchup-free), which is a 3d modelling tool. There was no simulation involved, only careful application of known rules.

Answer (score 5):

There is [QTop](https://github.com/jacobmarks/QTop) which is an open-source project that can simulate but also visualize topological quantum codes.